# WinForms: Changing ForeColor of Selected item in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I am setting the ForeColor of all items in my ListView to a different color, but this get's overrided when the item is selected (changes to Black again; changes back to custom color on deselection).

I want my items to retain my custom color, even in selection.

I'm basically asking the same question that was asked [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/292902/is-there-any-way-to-set-selected-item-forecolor-in-listview) 7 years ago, and doesn't seem to have any satisfactory answer.

I tried searching in SO and elsewhere, and no luck. The only solution provided so far is to draw the whole thing (the DrawItem method), which I gave a try but is ridiculously complicated for such a petty requirement...

Is this the only way? Say it ain't so.

Comment: Because of your requirement `even in selection` you will need to do a custom DrawItem method. Reason being is to override the Highlight ForeColor property when the highlighted item is drawn.
Sorry, No way around it that I know

Comment: Actually it is not that complicated. There are default drawing routines you cam use. What Viewmode is the LV in? Also: The user expects all selections to be highlighted in systemcolors.

Comment: `Say it ain't so.`  It is so.

Comment: `using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(e.Item.ForeColor))
                if (e.Item.Selected) e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font, br, e.Bounds.X + 4, e.Bounds.Y); 
                else e.DrawText();` - To make the selection stick out you could use a bold font..

Comment: It's two lines of code. Four, if you change ForeColor/BackColor on Selected. However, there can be some overhead to accomodate the logic behind *all items in my ListView have a different color*. But, if this logic is pre-defined, the overhead is very low.

Comment: @TaW I need to support all views (tiles, thumbnails, list, details, etc), and each item consists of image and text (Icons for each folder/file + name of the file) so I have to compensate for that with positioning... If I use your code and pinpoint it in the details view, will it mess other views ?

Comment: The code will probably not work too well for other views. One would have to test it, though and adapt it.

Answer (score 3):

Enable your ListView `OwnerDraw` mode, then subscribe its `DrawItem` and `DrawColumnHeader` events.
If your design requires it, also subcribe the `DrawSubitem` event.

At this point, you can draw anything in the related areas of your ListView.

In the example, I've painted a little symbol in the Header area.
The **Header** text needs to be painted too.

If the **Background color** doesn't change (same as in design mode), you just need to use the `DrawListViewItemEventArgs e` parameter function `e.DrawBackground();`

If not, use `e.Graphics.FillRectangle()` to color the Item area, defined by `e.Bounds`.

The **Item Text** is drawn using `e.Graphics.DrawString()`.
The item Text is `e.Item.Text`, the **text area** is defined by `e.Bounds` again.
If you don't need any specific details/settings for the item's text, you can simply use **`e.DrawText();`**, which uses the **default properties** (defined at design-time).

Here, the item color *complex logic* is that the color is specified inside the item text. Could be anything else. The item tag, its Index position, a `List<Parameters>`, you name it.

This is how it might look like:
(I added `e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = []` to show how you can control the quality of the rendered text. `e.Graphics.TextContrast` can be also used to enhance the contrast).

[image: ListView Colored Items]

**Note**: this code sample only draws a generic image, if the ListView has an ImageList. You should also verify whether the SmallIcon/LargeIcon ImageLists are defined and draw the related Image in the specified size. It's the same procedure, though.

```
protected void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = true;
    int imageOffset = 0;
    Rectangle rect = e.Item.Bounds;
    bool drawImage = !(e.Item.ImageList is null);
    Color itemColor = Color.FromName(e.Item.Text.Substring(e.Item.Text.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1));
    using (var format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.FitBlackBox)) {
        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        if (drawImage) {
            imageOffset = e.Item.ImageList.ImageSize.Width + 1;
            rect.Location = new Point(e.Bounds.X + imageOffset, e.Item.Bounds.Y);
            rect.Size = new Size(e.Bounds.Width - imageOffset, e.Item.Bounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(e.Item.ImageList.Images[e.Item.ImageIndex], e.Bounds.Location);
        }

        if (e.Item.Selected) {
            using (var bkgrBrush = new SolidBrush(itemColor))
            using (var foreBrush = new SolidBrush(e.Item.BackColor)) {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bkgrBrush, rect);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font, foreBrush, rect, format);
            }
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
        else {
            //e.DrawDefault = true;
            using (var foreBrush = new SolidBrush(itemColor)) {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font, foreBrush, rect, format);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Draws small symbol in the Header beside the normal Text
protected void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    string extra = (e.ColumnIndex == 1) ? (char)32 + "\u2660" + (char)32 : (char)32 + "\u2663" + (char)32;
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)) { 
        e.Graphics.DrawString(extra + e.Header.Text, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    }
}
```